# How to create generic and specific directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I need to create generic "information boxes" that will be repeated over and over again in a web app.
I need 3 different types of this boxes, let's say A, B and C.
Their templates will be very similar, so I was thinking to create a "generic box" and then in some way make it more specific depending if I need the directive A, B or C.

Let's take the image below as example:
[image]

The spaces marked in green may or may not exist depending on which directive we are using, and of course their content and behaviour should change accordingly.

As you can see the main directive is just a rectangle with some basic recurring info, like an image on the left, a title and a content area.

Is there any way to create a generic directive in angular (like the main rectangle) and then using some sort of inheritance to create the "sub-directive"?

If yes, is it possible to use only the main directive and passing it a parameter to let angular understand if from it should it create a directive A, B or C?
Something like

```
<my-generic-directive type="A"></my-generic-directive>
<my-generic-directive type="B"></my-generic-directive>
```

What are the possible drawbacks of this technique? 
I Hope I was clear

Comment: You can use the type to hide or show template elements. There's also the way for using dinamyc templates based on parameters.

Comment: no drawbacks, that's what directives are intended for

Comment: @charlietfl I see,thanks. In particular I'm trying to maximize the reusability of a (generic) directive, and I still haven't found many things on the argument either on the official guide or somewhere else.